# Dynamically defining top level routes in Phoenix routes.ex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What I would like to do is to dynamically route top level paths depending on slugs that are available for a specific model in the DB, like how GitHub does for user/org names like `https://github.com/elixir-lang` and `https://github.com/phoenixframework`, but I can't seem to get my head around it in the PhoenixFramework.

What I've tried so far, in my `routes.ex` is:

```
Enum.each(MyApp.Repo.all(MyApp.User), fn section ->
  get "/#{user.username}", UserController, :show, assigns: %{"username" => user.username}
end)
```

but I end up with the following error when it tries to compile the app:

```
== Compilation error on file web/router.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) repo MyApp.Repo is not started, please ensure it is part of your supervision tree
    lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:91: Ecto.Query.Planner.cache_lookup/3
    lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:72: Ecto.Query.Planner.query/4
    lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:91: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
    lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:15: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
    web/router.ex:25: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:669: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`routes.ex` is DSL, that is parsed during compilation time, not in runtime. First two words in error message are `Compilation error`. This means, that you can't use database in your routes.

Instead, try defining top level route like this:

```
get /:user_slug, UserController, :show
```

In your controller, check if this user exist in db and return 404, if not.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post about how to do this:

http://www.adamcz.com/blog/pretty-urls-with-phoenix

If you already have slugs in the database, you just need to specify the param in your router file:

```elixir
resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, ...], param: "slug"
```

and then look for that param in your controller:

```elixir
def show(conn, %{"slug" => slug}) do
  user = Repo.get_by(User, slug: slug)
  # ...
end
```